# Compatibility mode in ice cream sandwich tablet?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, tablet

I read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html) about compatibility mode. I got an ICS tablet and can't find anything to enable or disable it.

The layout of my app looks messed up. It's not zoomed. Zoom is better, I'm not working on this app anymore (can't optimize), and it's more acceptable.

The link has these 2 relevant options:

> - Your application has set both android:minSdkVersion and android:targetSdkVersion to "10" or lower and does not explicitly declare support for large screens using the  element.
> - Your application has set either android:minSdkVersion or android:targetSdkVersion to "11" or higher and explicitly declares that it does not support large screens, using the  element.

Where the first one is the correct for me.

I tried out different things in the manifest:

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="7"
    />
```

And this (also tried removing this entry):

```
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="false" />
```

Nothing helps, the layout looks exactly the same, and I don't see options about it on the device.

What do I have to do? Thanks.

Manifest requested by comment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="x"
    android:versionCode="x"
    android:versionName="x.x.x" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="7"
        />

<!--     <supports-screens android:largeScreens="false" /> -->

    <application
        android:name=".x"
        android:icon="@drawable/x"
        android:label="@string/x"
        android:debuggable="false"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            android:name="x"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
                   <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="x"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: So you're trying to force the "Zoomed" layout?

Comment: What do you mean with "force"? The docs says it's the default mode if the listed requirements are meet.

Comment: From your question, it's not clear what you actually want to do.

Comment: Of course I want to zoom it, do I have another alternative? I think it's very clear.

Comment: Hm, I see. With what Android SDK version are you compiling the app?

Comment: I tried with 2.1, now I tried with 4.2 and still the same.

Comment: Add your current, *full* Manifest to the question.

Comment: Ah! I got it! `<supports-screens android:largestWidthLimitDp="300" />    `

Comment: Looks so much better zoomed than this disaster... Strange although that `android:compatibleWidthLimitDp` doesn't work, or I can't find the option to enable it on the device.

Comment: Or use `<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="false" />` with an **x**

Comment: xlargeScreens also didn't work

Comment: I guess the problem reduces to that in all these cases, the compatibility mode is optional, and the device (Nexus 7) or Android version (4.2.1) doesn't show me an option to enable it. Or I'm to stupid to find it.

Comment: Well, but not I have another issue. If I set `largestWidthLimitDp` to more than 320, the tablet doesn't zoom. But as soon as I set 320, the Galaxy Nexus (smartphone 720x1280), which is already optimized, starts zooming. I don't get that... dip is density independent, the dips from the shortest side from the tablet are much more than 320. Why it doesn't zoom anymore on 321 dip?